# How can I export a csv file on a remote server using ssh?

Tags: r, unix, ssh

I would like to export my dataframe as a csv file and save it on a server using an ssh connexion.

The following command line doesn't work :

```
zz <- pipe('ssh -l username ip "touch /var/data/toto.csv"', "w")
write.csv(toto, file = zz, append = TRUE)
close(zz)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried scp command? example:

`scp /var/data/toto.csv username@ip:/destination/dir`

Before scp please write a file.

I think it will be hard to stream file to server, you can write a chunk of file and then scp it.  Have you tried a Rcurl library for R?

Comment: That's what I do but this assume that you create a local copy and then copy this local file on the remote server. Is it possible to do it directly on the remote server from R ?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have a key installed so that `ssh` doesn't ask for a password:

```
zz = pipe('ssh -l username ip "cat >/var/data/toto.csv"', 'w')
write.csv(toto, zz)
close(zz)
```

Use `>>` instead of `>` with `cat` if you really want to append.